# window.opener is null when trying to pass an object from one page to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open, window.opener, window.parent

there are few similar questions to this, but none of the solutions worked in my case.
I am pretty new at this, so the problem could also be a basic thing that i'm missing.

On the event of click, I am trying to open a new tab with the clicked object,
so for now i'm just trying to alert it in the new tab.

the parent window code:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(){

    var toSend = $(this);

    var newTab = window.open("test.html", "_blank");

    newTab.myData = toSend; // this one was a solution for a similar problem, 
                            // didn't work for me.
});
```

this is the opened window:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log(window.parent.toSend);

    console.log(window.parent.myData);

    console.log(myData);

    console.log(window.opener.toSend);


});
```

first 2 logs are returning "undefined", and the third is throwing an exception that myData is not defined (Uncaught ReferenceError: myData is not defined).
for the latter log i get "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match."

Help will be much appreciated, thank you!

edit: console.log(toSend) does log the proper object, and is defined.

Comment: do you run your file from the file system? like file://? or like http://?

Comment: from the file system

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `toSend` is a **local** variable inside a function. To be accessible on the `window` object, it has to be a **global** variable. One way to create a global variable from within a function is to assign to a property on `window`. So:

```
$(document).on("click", ".button", function(){

    window.toSend = $(this);

    var newTab = window.open("test.html", "_blank");
});
```

and then

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.log(window.opener.toSend);

});
```

---

That said, global variables are best avoided, so if you have to do this with multiple pieces of information, use a **single** global variable which refers to an object (using a name that's unlikely to conflict with things), and put the individual pieces of information on that object as properties.

Comment: Thanks, window.parent.toSend's value is still undefined. I think maybe the window.parent is not giving what I am expecting. I wrote "window.parent" in console, what should I look for to check if I'm getting the desired effect? Thanks again!

Comment: @user3445972: Sorry, it should be `window.opener`. `parent` is for frames accessing their container. I've fixed the answer.

Comment: Ok, now I still get "Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "null" from accessing a frame with origin "null". Protocols, domains, and ports must match." (window.opener is null). But now I tried it on firefox - and it works! apparently chrome restricts pop up windows to get/set values of window.opener. Any ideas how to bypass that?

Comment: Don't worry, that's because you're opening it from your file system (the URL is `file://....`). When you open it from a real web server (the URL is `http://...` or `https://...`), you won't have that issue with Chrome. (This is why Simon asked that question in a comment on the question.) When writing/debugging web pages, it's best to do so with a web server, not by opening files directly. There are small differences in what browsers do with local files vs. web pages.